# grep transformed content via od and show original file location

Tags: bash, unix, command-line-interface, od

I am transforming some binary files and grepping a value in them:

```
od -t uL * | grep 0000
```

this is showing the matches that I am after but it's not showing the filename, and if I do use `grep` with the `-H` flag I only get 'standard input':

```
od -t uL * | grep -H 0000
(standard input):xxx 0000
(standard input):yyy 0000
```

How can I get the original filename returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is lost by the time `grep` is run, so you might have to loop over the files yourself

```
for f in *; do
    od -t uL "$f" | awk -v f="$f" '/0000/ {print f":"$0}'
done
```

Comment: I suspected this would be the answer but I thought maybe there was a way around it. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for updating, that `{` was indeed unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This way, you can't. The grep command is working on the standard input stream, not on files. You could do a for loop in the shell, echo-ing the file name if the exit code from the grep command is zero (selected lines are found).